# Creating an orbit animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to make an animation with CSS. I need to rotate the images following the lines in the orbit, is not a circle. Its like a ellipse.
Like this image.

[Image showing how should be the movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyHrU.png)

Here is some demo of what I managed to do
https://codesandbox.io/s/orbit-animation-xhw3o

Any help will be appreciate =D

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the orbits `d` property from your `header-image.svg` file, and use them as CSS motion paths.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Motion_Path

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).